# Webpack - Output Files are not generating

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am creating a simple react app using webpack as the bundler and nodejs for creating a server. The thing is my webpack is not generating the output files in the destination folder. I am not seeing any error and `http://localhost:3000` shows my expected content, but the `dist` folder is not generated.

Is this something related to hot-module-reloding, and webpack is generating everything from memory for me. I am not sure.  I am new to react and any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './src/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
    }]
  }
};
```

**package.json**

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "lint": "eslint src"
  },
//remaining dependencies
```

**server.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
var config = require('./webpack.config');

new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), {
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
  hot: true,
  historyApiFallback: true
}).listen(3000, 'localhost', function (err, result) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }

  console.log('Listening at http://localhost:3000/');
});
```

Comment: are you running webpack-dev-server or webpack?

Comment: Ohh, got it. I was running webpack-dev-server. Thanks. webpack did the job for me.

Comment: Can you please tell me the difference between running webpack-dev-server and webpack.

Comment: webpack-dev-server doesnt write the files to disk .. it serves the file over a port similar to what express does for static files. running webpack actually writes and saves the file to your output path.

Answer (score 1):

you should use 'webpack' instead of 'webpack-dev-server', coz 'webpack' do generate your code to the disk while 'webpack-dev-server' just serve your code to your localhost